# Polymer - Dynamic page title with app-header

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

I'm using the app-drawer-layout from Polymer App Toolbox, and instead of having a fixed title in `<div main-title>My App</div>`, I'd like to have it work dynamically with the `iron-pages`-navigation.

Ideally I'd like to specify the title in each element loaded in `iron-pages`, but defining it in the navigation is also a solution. However, I'm kinda stuck as none of the attempts I've made seems to work.

My code looks like this:

```
<app-header condenses fixed effects="waterfall">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="mdi:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title>My App</div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <moso-profile name="profile"></moso-profile>
  <moso-resume name="resume"></moso-resume>
  <moso-portfolio name="portfolio"></moso-portfolio>
  <moso-contact name="contact"></moso-contact>
</iron-pages>
```

Now, I've tried using the `<content select=".page-title"></content>` ([Polymer Docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/local-dom#dom-distribution)) and then have a `<div class="page-title">New title</div>` in each loaded element. Didn't work.

I've also tried adding a `title` attribute to each element in `iron-pages` (like so: `<moso-profile title="Profile" name="profile"></moso-profile>`) and then try to one/two way bind it with `[[page.title]]`, no luck either.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is it not possible anymore?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not something like this?

```
<app-header condenses fixed effects="waterfall">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="mdi:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title>{{page}}</div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>

<iron-pages role="main" selected="[[page]]" attr-for-selected="name">
  <moso-profile name="profile"></moso-profile>
  <moso-resume name="resume"></moso-resume>
  <moso-portfolio name="portfolio"></moso-portfolio>
  <moso-contact name="contact"></moso-contact>
</iron-pages>
```

or if you want to control the title even more you can use a computed function:

```
<app-header condenses fixed effects="waterfall">
  <app-toolbar>
    <paper-icon-button icon="mdi:menu" drawer-toggle></paper-icon-button>
    <div main-title>{{_computeTitle(page)}}</div>
  </app-toolbar>
</app-header>
```

and in javascript:

```
_computeTitle: function(page) {
    if (page == 'profile') {
        return 'My Profile';
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It is not very flexible. Using this pattern you end up with dozens of functions like `_computeTitle` in one file. It's the current page that should decide what the title should look like. It would be great if one could use an application's insertion point from the page but that's not possible. My opinion is that this example shows that Polymer sucks. It is suitable only for very simple or very incapsulated things not for building apps with complex logic.